# What happens when you level up in Temple Run 2?

Tags: temple-run-2

I know that when you get to level 9 you get a gem powerup or something, but what happens at other levels? If you get past level 9 do you get a prize or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing really happens. As you mentioned, you unlock the gem ability at level 9, but that's about it. They might add something in the future.

You do however get +1 score multiplier for each level-up objective you complete. So if you're going for that *Radical High Score™*, you're gonna want to complete all of them.

Answer (score -3):

Completing level 9 gets you 9000 coins. and a glitch where pause no longer works.

Comment: Yes, but what about levels 10 and up?